# How to get a group of attributes associated with another group of attributes?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

This should be really simple but I'm having a weird amount of trouble finding an answer. I just want a group of records associated via foreign key to another group of records. For example, if I have Song belongs_to Artist via Song.artist_id, and I have a group of Artists via `Artist.where(mustache: true)`, I want a query that returns all the Songs belonging to all those Artists. So something like:

```
@songs = Artist.where(mustache: true).songs
```

but that actually works.

Comment: Read the [rails guides on associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and sit down with a piece of paper or a UML program and draw up the objects in your domain and plan the relations between them.

Comment: `Song.where(artist_id: Artist.where(mustache: true))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Song.where(artist_id: Artist.where(mustache: true).select(:id))`

Or

`song.joins(:artist).where(artists: {mustache: true})`

Comment: Better to use `select` instead of `pluck` in the first query, it will create just one sql statement instead of two